Integrating $\int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$
this is the question we got on our assignment:
$$\int\frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}dx$$
nobody could solve this, everybody was trying whatever they knew but this just couldn't be solved. somebody solve this please.

Duplicate1

Duplicate2

"nobody could solve this, everybody was trying whatever they knew but this just couldn't be solved."  - really?

Notice that $$ \frac{x^2+x}{(e^x+x+1)^2}=\frac{(x+1)e^{-x}\cdot xe^{-x}}{(e^{-x}(1+x)+1)^2}$$
while  $\frac{d}{dx}(1+e^{-x}(1+x))=-xe^{-x}$. Try doing integration by parts, the answer should come out as
$$\frac{1+x}{e^x+1+x}-\ln(1+e^{-x}(1+x))+C$$
